# How to send user data object along with token to the angular front-end using node?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6, jwt, mean

At the time of signup and login I want to send User's data along with JWT so that I can update current users profile data.

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    let userData = req.body;
    let user = new User(userData);

    user.save((err, registeredUser) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            let payload =  { subject : registeredUser._id }
            let token = jwt.sign(payload, 'abcd');
            res.status(200).send({token});
        }
    });
});
```

How can I send registeredUser object along with token.

Comment: Instate of send use `res.json()` it'll return data in the JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways :

1. Simple and crude: `res.status(200).send({token, user})`
2. Expose custom headers from your backend and send the token as part of the response. Then you can use the response body to simply send the user/resource data. `res.status(200).send({user})`.

Usually #2 is a better design, since the token is more like a auth/session information and can be intercepted using custom middleware/filters (eg:PassportJS) on the backend and always attached as part of the request headers from the front-end using Angular interceptors.

Express config options: headers.https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options